# How to use client template expressions in ajax binding of a mvc kendo grid?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a two-layer hierarchical grid that I am moving from server side binding to using ajax. The ajax reads for both layers of data are working correctly however I am having difficulty using the ClientTemplate to render my columns based on conditional logic.

Below is the server-side binding version. I understand I have to use ClientTemplate and expressions #=# for the same effect but I am having two problems:

1. How to increment variable 'i' for each row so I can use CheckBoxFor and like html helper methods?
2. How to convert the @ to use the ClientTemplate expression. Note the conditional logic uses properties of the Model of the View and also properties of the bound element (MyViewModel) with the conditional logic using a mixture of properties from the Model

Converting this to an expression would be most helpful.

```
var i = -1;

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(c => c.Selected).Title("")
      .Template(
        @<text>
          @{i++;}
          @if (Model.Permissions.HasInsertAccess && item.Status == Status.Created)
          {
            <input type="hidden" name="MyViewModels.Index" value="@i" />
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyViewModels[i].Selected)
          }
          </text>);

          columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
            .Template(@<text>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyViewModels[i].Id)@item.Id</text>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**VIEW**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModels

<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNumber = 0;

function resetRowNumber(e) {
    rowNumber = 0;
}

function renderNumber(data) {
    return ++rowNumber;
}

function renderRecordNumber(data) {
    var page = parseInt($("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page()) - 1;
    var pagesize = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize();
    return parseInt(rowNumber + (parseInt(page) * parseInt(pagesize)));
}

</script>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.TestModels>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);

    columns.Template(t => { }).Title("Row No").ClientTemplate("# if ( '" + @Model.Permissions.HasValue.ToString().ToLower() + "' == 'true') { #" +
        "<input type='text' name='MyViewModels.Index' value='#= renderNumber(data) #' /> " +
        "# } #");

})
.Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 50 }).Refresh(true))
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Home"))

)
    .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("resetRowNumber"))
)
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        TestModels model = new TestModels();
        model.Permissions = true; //Please comment this line and check
        return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
        List<TestModels> models = new List<TestModels>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            TestModels t1 = new TestModels();
            t1.ID = i;
            t1.Name = "Name" + i;
            models.Add(t1);

        }

        return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class TestModels
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool? Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Please try with the above code snippet. 
Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks, works well. Instead of using a row increment I decided to use the uid generated by the kendo-grid. It's a shame the client template does not work well with mvc html classes as I now have to hand write the ugly html. Do you know if it's possible to mix serverside with ajax binding? The first grid from the Model and then when you expand the row to make an ajax call? I tried numerous ways to no avail.